# Problem when connect sequelize on express with postgreSQL

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I have a little problem with connecting sequelize in express

```
 TypeError: sequelize.sync is not a function
```

I have database setup in docker

```
database:
    image: postgres
    container_name: database
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
      POSTGRES_DB: express_database
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

And this is my sequelize define

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    'express_database',
    'postgres',
    'secret',
    {
        host: 'database',
        dialect: 'postgres'
    }
);

export default { sequelize }
```

And in index.js

```
import sequelize from './Util/database.js'
(async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.sync({
            force: false
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
})()
```

And my user model

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import db from '../Util/database';

const User = db.define('users',  {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    first_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
});

export default { User }
```

I struggled all day and searched for information but I don't realize what the problem might be. Do you know how I can solve this whole thing?
Is it a problem that I wrote the code with es6?

Comment: Did you try `import { sequelize } from './Util/database.js'`

Comment: The requested module './Util/database.js' does not provide an export named 'sequelize'

Comment: Ok, forget it. Can you set a breakpoint or output `sequelize` instance to check what it contains?

Comment: Try taking out the { } from the export default.  `export default sequelize`

Answer (score 0):

`export default { sequelize }` exports an object with only 1 key named 'sequelize' and containing what you want.

Replace it with `export default sequelize`. Otherwise, you'd be forced to call `sequelize.sequelize.sync()` when you import it^^